# Gparted can't resize Ubuntu partition /dev/sda9

Tags: partitioning, gparted

Why can't I resize the `/dev/sda9` partition? I have plenty of unallocated space for it.

[image: Gparted screenshot with unallocated space to the left of sda9]

Answer (score 0):

You can't resize a partition that is mounted. Thats why there are a key/lock symbol at it.  /dev/sda9 is your root (/) partition.

Boot on a live media and run gparted from there.

Comment: You type faster then  me.

Comment: Thanks for all of you, it's help me a lot!